# GNU Make: detect Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gnu-make, bison

I would want to run `sed 's/#line/\/\/#line/'` on some particular docs in order to automate [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30062477/1737973) to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512580/.

I would want that command to be ran by GNU Make automatically only when invoked from Xcode.

Can't just simply use `uname -s` detection of `Darwin` because a Homebrew only toolchain is to be maintained in parallel to the Xcode project configuration docs. It has to specifically detect Xcode somehow.

My Xcode right now is reported as `Version 9.0 (9A235)`.

Got ideas?

Comment: Set a `-DXCODE` argument in the XCode configuration?

Comment: Or, perhaps you can detect from the contents of the lines whether they are the problematic sort or not, e.g., by `grep`ing first and only doing the `sed` if the pattern is found.

Comment: `-DXCODE` would define XCODE for the C preprocessor, right? I would need to detect Xcode at the upper level: at the GNU Make level. Maybe some kind of environment injection would do, but I don't know exactly what or how...

Comment: I'm not sure how you are calling `make` from XCode, but if you can affect the command-line, it is definitely possible to give `XCODE=1` as an argument to `make` itself (edit: the syntax is not `-DXCODE`, sorry about that). However, even if it is just for the C compiler, XCode might pass that in `CFLAGS` or similar to `make` so in a convoluted way you might even be able to detect that.

Comment: Hmm I wasn't even calling Make at all. I didn't know how to configure it and apparently ended up just adding the sources manually to the `*.xcodeproj/` materials and calling GNU Make (macOS High Sierra default 3.81, not Homebrew's) from Terminal in order to refresh the Bison parser C source. But that's wrong, I'd want to finish configuration of the `*.xcodeproj/` materials including calling Make from Xcode.

Comment: I guess I used `File` > `New` > `Project` > `Command Line Tool`, Xcode then creating a simple framework from which to just select and add C/C++ source docs to the project.

Comment: I think I got it in the end. I have to try again cleanly, but I ended up with two targets, one which builds the program itself, the other with the Make call. Now I'd need to have link the Make call as a pre action for the program somehow. Once got that then your comment would apply as accepted answer if you convert it to answer...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to get rid of the `#line` generated by Bison.  Then, pass it `--no-lines` (aka `-l`) or put `%no-lines` in the grammar file.

Comment: I'll use `--no-lines` instead of manipulating the generated parser. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Strictly concerning the question of how to detect XCode in `make`, it seems that the answer would be to add a flag to the command-line (e.g., `make XCODE=1`) or to the environment. I don't think there is an automatic XCode-specific flag set to distinguish it from a Mac that is using otherwise the same tools.

For the specific case of getting rid of `#line` generated by Bison, it seems that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52680919/204883) may be better. Or if neither of these is doable, I would seek to detect the undesired situation (e.g., with `grep` or `awk`) first rather than unconditionally running `sed`.

Comment: I'm having some trouble to get the pipeline truly working in Xcode, but except the Xcode part, this is already working. Actually I should have realized by myself.